# using coolprop for a gui model in C# Visual Studios

Tags: c#, user-interface, model

I am fairly new to programming and for my final year project, I am tasked to create a graphical user interface for a crossflow heat exchanger.

I have already created the front end and back end of the model and I am told to use [coolprop](http://www.coolprop.org/) to derive the thermal properties of the fluids. However, since I do not have much experience in programming, I am having a problem troubleshooting the errors.

Is there anyone who have used coolprop for a C# project and could help guide me?
I have already added the coolprop dll and cs files to the project but when I start the project, I get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
>
> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'CoolProp': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Comment: At first glance it seems your missing a reference to the DLL file of CoolProp?

Comment: expand the "references" node in the solution explorer. is the reference there, and valid? has it been installed to GAC, or does the physical (local) path match that shown in reference properties? could be a secondary dependency: DllNotFoundException [is not thrown when the common language runtime is unable to load a .NET Framework assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dllnotfoundexception.aspx)